# Code is not executable because of "the type MyComparator1 already exists" error

Tags: java, collections, comparator, comparable, treeset

In the code below I am trying to use **Comparable** and **Comparator** Interfaces for Default and Customized Sorting on my own defined Employee class respectively. But i get an error near the class "MyComparator1" which says "*the type MyComparator1 already exists*". On compilation, it gives *"NullPointerException"*. Can anyone let me know what's going wrong in the code?

```
package CollectionsPkg;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class TreeSetDemo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Employee e1=new Employee(20, "Catherine");
        Employee e2=new Employee(36, "Helena");
        Employee e3=new Employee(9, "Mathews");
        Employee e4=new Employee(23, "Goblet");
        Employee e5=new Employee(5, "Andrew");
        
        
        TreeSet t=new TreeSet();    
        t.add(e1);
        t.add(e2);
        t.add(e3);
        t.add(e4);
        t.add(e5);
        System.out.println("For Default sorting: "+t);
        
        TreeSet t1=new TreeSet(new MyComparator1());
        t1.add(e1);
        t1.add(e2);
        t1.add(e3);
        t1.add(e4);
        t1.add(e5);
        System.out.println("Customized Sorting based on Alphabetical order: "+t1);
    }

}

class Employee implements Comparable{

    int eid;
    String ename;
    
    Employee(int eid,String ename){
        eid=this.eid;
        ename=this.ename;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return eid+" "+ename;
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        
        int eid1= this.eid;
        Employee e=(Employee)obj;
        int eid2=e.eid;
        
        if(eid1<eid2) {
            return -1;                  
        }
        else if(eid1>eid2) {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        return 0;
    }
    
}

class MyComparator1 implements Comparator{
    public int compare(Object obj1,Object obj2) {

        Employee e1=(Employee)obj1;
        Employee e2=(Employee)obj2;
        
        String s1=e1.ename;
        String s2=e2.ename;
        
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ename=this.ename;`? That is not how you assign variables in java. You want to swap it to `this.ename=ename;` and then it will all work

Comment: Are you following some ancient tutorial? You should definitely use Generics here. And putting all classes into a single source file, is discouraged as it can lead to errors like the one you encountered (“type … already exists”). Unless you use the rather new feature to run a single-source Java program directly. Then, this error couldn’t occur.